# Where can i find information about jsp .createGrid?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp

Currently, I am looking for a code to learn.
It is a JSP file.

I want to know which website contains information about the grid (ex. columns, properties, events...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var isAdded = "<%=Const.BOOLEAN_FALSE%>";
        //요청할 URL grid
        var emxaple = $("#emxaple").createGrid({
            columns : [ blah blah blah],            
            properties: { blah blah blah },             
            events : { 
                    RowChanged: function(row1, row2) {
                    isAdded = "<%=Const.BOOLEAN_FALSE%>";
                    },
                    EndQuery: function(message) {
                        if(emxaple.GetRowCount() == 0){
                        } 
                        else {
                            isUserAdd = "<%=Const.BOOLEAN_FALSE%>";
                            var row = blahblah.GetRow({});
                        }
                    },

                    EndSave : function(message) {
```

Comment: You might have JSP file, but the code is JavaScript, using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) library, just with some value assignments using JSP. So you have to check what jQuery grid plug-in is used, and read its documentation.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it long time ago that it was my mistake. but anyway thanks a lot